# Java ArrayOutofBound

Tags: java, arrays

So Im trying to make a program that counts how many numbers and letters a string has and save the numbers in an array of ints and the letters in an array of chars but it keeps throwing the out of bounce error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String s = k.nextLine();

        int spaceCount = 0;
        int[] intarray;
        char[] charArray;
        int numCount = 0;
        int letterCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {


            if (Character.toString(s.charAt(i)).matches("[0-9]")) {


                numCount++;

            } else if (Character.toString(s.charAt(i)).matches("[a-zA-Z]")) {

                letterCount++;


            }else {

                continue;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(numCount);
        System.out.println(letterCount);

        intarray = new int[numCount];
        charArray = new char[letterCount];



            for (int i = 0; i <s.length(); i++) {


                if (Character.toString(s.charAt(i)).matches("[0-9]")) {

                    intarray[i] = s.charAt(i);
                    continue;
                }else if (Character.toString(s.charAt(i)).matches("[a-zA-Z]")){


                    charArray[i] = s.charAt(i);
                    continue;




                }




            }

            for (int i =0;i<intarray.length;i++){

                System.out.println(intarray[i]);
            }

            for (int i=0;i<charArray.length;i++){

                System.out.println(charArray[i]);
            }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't use `intarray[i]` and `charArray[i]` in your second loop. You need separate indices for those arrays (to count the current digit or char respectively).

Comment: Before I read any further, a quick note: are you sure you're getting an ArrayOutOf**Bounce error**?

Comment: This is what Im getting

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: He's probably talking about something like this :-) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yx62tt1Ci4U  Hint George:  "bounce" and "bounds" are different words in English.  They don't even *sound* the same if you pronounce them correctly.